# Attenuation does not get applied correctly

Tags: opengl, lighting

I can't understand does the light attenuation correctly get applied or not.

[image]

It seems like it's not because the shininess of the steel frame for cube located at `(-500, 100, 100)`(at the left) is too much highlighted - must be less I think, considering that the light position (white cube) is `(100.0, 100.0f, 100.0f)`.

I'm using this formula to get the attenuation

```
1.0 / (constant + linear * distance + quadratic * (distance^2))
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 450 core

struct Material {
    sampler2D diffuse;
    sampler2D specular;
    float shininess;
};

struct Light {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;    
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;
};

uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
uniform Material material;
uniform Light light;    
in vec3 vNormal;
in vec2 vTexCoord;
in vec4 fragPosition;
out vec4 color;

void main() {
    vec3 norm = vNormal;
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - vec3(fragPosition.xyz));
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(cameraPosition - vec3(fragPosition.xyz));
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);

    vec3 ambient  = light.ambient * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, vTexCoord));
    vec3 diffuse  = light.diffuse * max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0) * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, vTexCoord));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0f), material.shininess) * vec3(texture(material.specular, vTexCoord));

    float d = length(lightDir);
    float attenuation = 1.0f / (light.constant + light.linear * d + light.quadratic * (d * d));


    ambient *= attenuation;
    diffuse *= attenuation;
    specular *= attenuation;

    color = vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular, 1.0f);
}
```

And passing the following values to the program

```
glUniform1f(lightConstantLoc,  1.0);
glUniform1f(lightLinearLoc,    0.1);
glUniform1f(lightQuadraticLoc, 0.01);
```

Also same positions but changed the view angle

[image]
So what's wrong there? Are my calculations wrong? What's going there?

Comment: The code looks correct at a first glance -- maybe just don't hardcode `1.0f` as the light intensity (that you divide by the attenuation) but add another uniform that you can tune and set to a bigger value?

Comment: Unrelated: don't do three multiplications and a sum at the end, do the sum first and *one* multiplication (`attenuation * (ambient + diffuse + specular)`).

Comment: @peppe i tried with one multiplication and change the light specular component but still nothing really changed.

Comment: No, not the light specular component, I'm talking about the formula `1.0 / (constant + linear * d + quadratic * d * d)`. That 1.0 is the intensity of your light, which may be very dim. Make it a uniform and try increasing it.

Comment: @peppe I just did that too, added uniform instead of `1.0` and with left and right keys was increasing and dicreasing `(+= 0.1 or -= 0.1)` the light intensity in the formula - but it looks like attenuation does not even applying - objects that are far away from the light source are not getting darker than closer ones. Is there any tools to debug the fragment shader output ?  I would like to compare the final fragment colors of the cubes with each to check if the color components are getting close to 0 or not considering their distances.

Comment: ***SNAP*** (aka: please have coffee and then read the code): `lightDir` has always length 1 because you normalize it...

Comment: @peppe ohh yeah exactly lol, just fixed that, now all the cubes are dark (not visible) except of the light source. I'm increasing the light intensity but objects are still not visible (dark)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113809/discussion-between-arammis-and-peppe).

Comment: @peppe I've finally figured this out. As I was thinking - the calculations were right, but the objects sizes had to be smaller to properly see the attenuation effect - so what I did is just made the cubes with the size of 1 and also changed all the appropriate positions (light position, cameraposition) and **the attenuation has been emphasized properly**. I don't understand why this worked ? seems like It's all the matter of a right values for everything ... but what's the rules to always get right values ?

Comment: That's basically why everyone today is switching to PBR -- Phong & friends are too ad-hoc and require constant tuning to get good effects. PBR "just works".

Comment: @peppe hmm interesting